# HTML5 Canvas Clip working when used along with explorercanvas

Tags: html, excanvas

Has anyone got HTML5 canvas clipping (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/) work with explorercanvas (http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas)?

I have an HTML5 page using clip() and to support older IE bowsers, I am using explorercanvas. But I couldn't get clipping region work on it. I am looking for a solution or workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clip() does not work in explorercanvas (excanvas.js).
Issue Reference:http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=36